# Split a parameter pack at a given type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++14, c++17

How can I split a parameter pack based on a given separator type? For example:

```
struct separator {
  // ...
};

struct foo1 {
  foo1(int a, int b) {...}
};

struct foo2 {
  foo2(double a, double b, double c) {...}
};

template <typename... ArgsT>
void func(ArgsT&&... args) {
   // args have two separators
   auto f1 = foo1(/*How can I get the argument list to construct foo1?*/);
   auto f2 = foo2(/*same as above*/);
   auto f3 = ....
}

separator s1, s2;
func(s1, 1, 2, s2, 4.5, 6.7, 7.8);
```

In the above example, the given `args` is guaranteed to have at least one argument of type `separator`. Each separator is followed by an argument list to construct a struct (e.g., `foo1` and `foo2` and so on). A C++14 or C++1z based solution will be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably best to *avoid* this sort of thing. Perhaps you should pass tuples which contain the parameters in question, or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I got it have a look:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
T recrusiveSearchHelper(int which,int current, T last)
{
    return last;
};
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T recrusiveSearchHelper(int which,int current,T first,Args... args)
{
    if (which == current)
    {
        return first;
    }
    recrusiveSearchHelper(which,current + 1,args...);
}
template <typename T,typename... Args>
T recrusiveSearch(int which, T first, Args... args)
{
    return recrusiveSearchHelper(which,0,first,args...);
}


struct Seperator 
{

};
void foo2(double a,double b,double d)
{
    std::cout << "Foo two: " << a << " : " << b << " : " << d << std::endl;
};
void foo1(int a,int b)
{
    std::cout << "Foo One: " << a << " : "<< b << std::endl;
};
void zipper(int& index,std::function<void(int)>fn, Seperator s)
{
    index++;
    fn(index);  
}
template <typename T>
void zipper(int& index, std::function<void(int)>fn, T data)
{
    index++;
};
template <typename T,typename... Args>
void zipper(int& index, std::function<void(int)> fn,T first, Args... args)
{
    index++;
    zipper(index,fn,args...);
};
template <typename... Args>
void zipper(int& index, std::function<void(int)> fn,Seperator first, Args... args)
{
    index++;
    fn(index);

    zipper(index,fn,args...);
};
template <typename T,typename... Args>
void useWithSeperator(T first,Args... args)
{
    int index = 0;
    int current = 0;
    std::function <void(int)> fn = [&current,first,args...](int where)
    {
        if (where - current == 3)
        {

            foo1(recrusiveSearch(where-3,first,args...),recrusiveSearch(where-2,first,args...));

        }else if (where - current == 4)
        {
            foo2(recrusiveSearch(where-4,first,args...),recrusiveSearch(where-3,first,args...),recrusiveSearch(where-2,first,args...));
        }
        current = where;
    };
    zipper(index,fn,first);
    zipper(index,fn,args...);
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    useWithSeperator(1,2,3,Seperator(),4,5,Seperator(),1,1,2,3,4,Seperator(),1,2,5,Seperator());
}
```

Its a bit messy however what this does is it runs through a helper varidiac template that narrows down our search range with each iteration until the Element first becomes the element at our desired position within its recursive cycle. The rest is rather simple we need to retrieve the data and keep track how long our cycle is.

I will add more detail to this answer soon.

Comment: Thanks. However, is this implementation made for foo1 with argument list known? In many of my cases, foo1 and foo2 can take variadic arguments.

Comment: Hmm how about if foo1 and 2 both take only variadic arguments? Is it okay if I pass additional information into foo1 and foo2 like the index within the sequence?

Answer (score -1):

First, instead of doing that, take tuples and construct your objects from said tuples.

```
func(std::make_tuple(1, 2), std::make_tuple(4.5, 6.7, 7.8));
```

We'll end up going here if we do the work anyhow.

Failing that, write a function that takes a `std::tuple<Ts...>` and splits it into a `std::tuple< std::tuple<???>... > tuple_of_tuples` split on your separator, then doing a `std::apply( good_func, tuple_of_tuples )`.

```
namespace details {
  struct adl_helper {};
  template<class Sep, class...Cs, class...Zs>
  auto tuple_splitter( adl_helper, std::tuple<> in, std::tuple<Cs...> working, std::tuple<Zs...> out ) {
    (void)in;
    return std::tuple_cat( std::move(out), std::make_tuple(working) );
  }
  template<class Sep, class T0, class...Ts, class...Cs, class...Zs,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T0, Sep>{}, int> =0
  >
  auto tuple_splitter( adl_helper, std::tuple<T0, Ts...> in, std::tuple<Cs...> working, std::tuple<Zs...> out ) {
    auto in_indexer = indexer<sizeof...(Ts)>();
    return tuple_splitter<Sep>(
      adl_helper{},
      in_indexer( [&](auto...i){ return std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<i+1>(std::move(in))...); } ),
      std::tuple_cat( std::move(working), std::make_tuple( std::get<0>(in) ) ), 
      std::move(out)
    );
  }
  template<class Sep, class...Ts, class...Cs, class...Zs>
  auto tuple_splitter( adl_helper, std::tuple<Sep, Ts...> in, std::tuple<Cs...> working, std::tuple<Zs...> out ) {
    auto in_indexer = indexer<sizeof...(Ts)>();
    return tuple_splitter<Sep>(
      adl_helper{},
      in_indexer( [&](auto...i){ return std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<i+1>(std::move(in))...); } ),
      std::make_tuple(),
      std::tuple_cat( std::move(out), std::make_tuple(working) )
    );
  }
}
template<class Sep, class...Ts>
auto tuple_splitter( std::tuple<Ts...> tuple ) {
  return details::tuple_splitter<Sep>( details::adl_helper{}, std::move(tuple), std::make_tuple(), std::make_tuple() );
}
```

now `tuple_splitter<Bob>( some_tuple )` will split `some_tuple` into a tuple-of-tuples, with each sub-tuple's elements delimited by `Bob`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6813f1edad50a308).

I use my `indexer` utility to pop the first element off a tuple.  It lets you get a compile-time pack of integers without leaving the current function body.

```
template<class=void,std::size_t...Is>
auto indexer( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto) {
    return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
  };
}
// takes a number N
// returns a function object that, when passed a function object f
// passes it compile-time values from 0 to N-1 inclusive.
template<std::size_t N>
auto indexer() {
  return indexer( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
```